# Warning about array initialization

Tags: c++

I'm trying to initialize an array to all zeros in a for loop written with c++:

```
for( int k=1; k<4; k++ ){

    p[n]={0};
    for(int k1=0; k1<n; k1++){

        x=x+y;
    }
}
```

but when I compile I get a warning saying:

warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]

Does anyone know what it means?
or What  I should do to not get that warning?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using `{}`? It needs to be used as part of array initialization but not during assignment.

Comment: Just so ya know, you can just do `x += y;` instead of `x = x + y;`

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use `int p[4] = {0};`? That has the same effect.

Comment: What is the declaration of the array?

Comment: I notice you start your loop at 1. Arrays are 0-based.

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that the initialization syntax you are using was introduced in C++11. In order to get rid of the warning, you must enable C++11 support in the compiler by passing -std=c++0x.

Also, I think you got your ks and ns mixed up in the code sample. As it is, the outer loop does the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 0):

int myArray[5]={0};
then you can initialize an array to all zeros !! 
just try !!